# Getting last entry of the months from mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Say the collection store data in the below format. Every day a new entry is added in the collection. Dates are in ISO format.

```
|id|dt|data|
---
|1|2021-03-17|{key:"A", value:"B"}
...
|1|2021-03-14|{key:"A", value:"B"}
...
|1|2021-02-28|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2021-02-27|{key:"A", value:"B"}
...
|1|2021-02-01|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2021-01-31|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2021-01-30|{key:"A", value:"B"}
...
|1|2021-01-01|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2020-12-31|{key:"A", value:"B"}
...
|1|2020-11-30|{key:"A", value:"B"}
...
```

I need help with a query that gives me the last day of each month for a given period of time. Below is the query I was able to do which is not giving last day of the current month as I am sorting it by day, month and year.

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
    {
      $match: {dt: {$gt: ISODate("2020-01-01")}
    },
    {
      $project: {
        dt: "$dt",
        month: {
          $month: "$dt"
        },
        day: {
          $dayOfMonth: "$dt"
        },
        year: {
          $year: "$dt"
        },
        data: "$data"
      }
    },
    {
        $sort: {day: -1, month: -1, year: -1}
    },
    { $limit: 24},
    {
        $sort: {dt: -1}
    },
])
```

The results I am after is:

```
|1|2021-03-17|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2021-02-28|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2021-01-31|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2020-12-31|{key:"A", value:"B"}
|1|2020-11-30|{key:"A", value:"B"}
...
|1|2020-01-31|{key:"A", value:"B"}
```

Comment: can you query iso format with datetime objects? If so, this could be an or query with each being ```$gte``` the last day of the month and ```$lt``` the first day of the month.

Comment: I updated my question. I need last entry of the month in the collection.

Comment: Do you need the last record in the database for each month, or the data for the last day of each month?

Answer (score 2):

Group the records by year and month, get the max date for that month.

```
db.getCollection('data').aggregate([
    { $match: { dt: { $gt: ISODate("2020-01-01") } } },
    { $group: { // group by
      _id: { $substr: ['$dt', 0, 7] }, // get year and month eg 2020-01
      dt: { $max: "$dt" }, // find the max date
      doc:{ "$first" : "$$ROOT" } } // to get the document
    },
    { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$doc"} }, // project the document
    { $sort: { dt: -1 } }
]);
```

[$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/)

[$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

[$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

[$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/)

[$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/)

Answer (score 0):

I monkey patched a possible solution for you in Python, but without your DB, I can't be positive that this works.

First there's a function that takes in an integer representing a month and returns the last day of that month.

```
import datetime as dt


def last_day_of_month(month):

    return dt.datetime(2021, month+1, 1) - dt.timedelta(days=1)
```

Next, I built the query with a separate function.

```
def build_query(last_month):

    return [
    {
        "$and": [
            {"date": {"$gte": last_day_of_month(i)}},
            {"date": {"$lt": last_day_of_month(i) + dt.timedelta(days=1)}}
        ]
    }
    for i in range(0, last_month)
]
```

Here's the output. It would be inside an `$or` operator in the `$match` stage.

```
    {'$match': {'$or': [{'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 31, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 28, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 31, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 30, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 31, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 30, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 31, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 31, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 30, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 1, 0, 0)}}]},
   {'$and': [{'date': {'$gte': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 30, 0, 0)}},
     {'date': {'$lt': datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0)}}]}]}}
```